# Google Drive iOS SDK file thumbnailLink fails with 404 error

Tags: ios, http-status-code-404, thumbnails, google-drive-api

In my application, when I use GTLDriveFile's thumbnailLink to download thumbnail for a file, it fails with not-found-on-the-server error(code 404). Here's an example of a file's thumbnailLink URL given by the Google Drive iOS SDK:

https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/eR-ahfZKPGcrqzhfh8Y4_tr7nwpdIdbkPxo19tjBeVPh0gE-QKSdT4fJrg8ajNhQ6g=s220

Also, I've noticed that the URLs fail most often for MS Word, MS Excel, and MS Powerpoint files; while they work just fine for PDFs, png files, and various other file types.

Is anyone else seeing the same issue? How did you resolve it?

Comment: I've got the same, and [Walter too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20617012/thumbnail-link-of-a-google-doc-doesnt-work).

Answer (score 0):

GTLServiceDrive * service...

Try

```
- (void)authorizeRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest *)request
       completionHandler:(void (^)(NSError *error))handler
```

Example:

```
NSURL * url = [ NSURL URLWithString:thumbnailLink ];
NSMutableURLRequest * request = [ NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url ];
[ service.authorizer authorizeRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSError *error)
     {
         NSURLSession * defaultSession = [ NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[ NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration ]
                                                                        delegate:nil
                                                                   delegateQueue:[ NSOperationQueue mainQueue ] ];
         NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask = [ defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                                              completionHandler:^(NSData * data, NSURLResponse * response, NSError * error)
                                            {
                                                NSHTTPURLResponse * httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
                                                if ([ httpResponse isKindOfClass:[ NSHTTPURLResponse class ] ] && httpResponse.statusCode == 200 && data)
                                                {
                                                    UIImage * image = [ UIImage imageWithData:data ];

                                                    ...
                                                }
                                            } ];
         [ dataTask resume ];
     } ];
```