# Thumbnail link of a google doc doesn't work

Tags: java, google-app-engine, thumbnails, google-drive-api, google-docs

I had done a java code to get the thumbnail link to the image of a google document file.getThumbnailLink() this code was working until the last thursday or friday, and now doesn't work... the result i'm getting is a message "Not Found Error 404" for the url: "https://docs.google.com/a/se.pe/feeds/vt?gd=true&id=1dDEYCOQTlpSy5izlcNz0dAq12ooD3cB5Gdqc1Wd4VV4&v=1&s=AMedNnoAAAAAUq9UYeDxDIprZfC2V8RnJd4gxWeVaXLw&sz=s220".

I think google has changed the format of this url, for example in the drive.google.com interface for the same thumbnail image I see: https://lh3.google.com/MO8uVrNxKRa3uvSmqtR5yUZ1ooSZtP5zDpLMtCdmeiA4CZB4MXNKeDN1ewEBdzJleHkKAEpShb-BcOor8lwQOKbtQk7x=w230-h212

Please help me to get again the code to obtain the thumbnail image of a google document.